# Dynamo DB partition key design: Few distinct partition keys but always a unique sort key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm new to DynamoDB and I'm struggling with designing a good partition key.
I read that a good DynamoDB uses a partition key with almost distinct values.
Nevertheless I wondered if I could use a DynamoDB with only ~10 (distinct) values for a partition key if I'm always able to use the sort key as a unique identifier (eq not startswith). Will I run into problems with this approach?

My **problem(s)** looks like this:

1.
Let's say I want to **visualize rooms in few houses**. Every room has IoT devices that should be visible in a kind of "room map". **Visualization is done and stored in a json format** locally at the moment. I want to store this configuration in the DynamoDB. My **partition key** would be the **houses** and the **sort key** would be a prefix with roomMap_ followed by the room name (unique for a partition key of course)

```
| partition key | sort key            | room map json |
|---------------|---------------------|---------------|
|        House1 | roomMap_livingRoom1 |         {...} |
|        House1 | roomMap_livingRoom2 |         {...} |
|        House1 | roomMap_kitchen     |         {...} |
|        House2 | roomMap_livingRoom1 |         {...} |
```

2.
Now I also want to **store dashboards for the IoT devices** in the DynamoDB. **DeviceIds are unique for a House (by design), but can be the same in other houses**. E.g. a device 'fridgeSensor' could exist in more than 1 house. The dashboard configuration is also stored as json.

```
| partition key              | dashboard config json |
|----------------------------|-----------------------|
| House1::fridgeSensor       |                 {...} |
| House1::temperatureSensor1 |                 {...} |
| House2::fridgeSensor       |                 {...} |
```

---

As I read that a **good DynamoDB design uses only 1 table** I thought about the following tabl by using PartitionKey of the first table design and adapt the sort key:

```
| partition key | sort key            | room map json | dashboard config json |
|---------------|---------------------|---------------|-----------------------|
|        House1 | roomMap_livingRoom1 |         {...} | null            
|        House1 | roomMap_livingRoom2 |         {...} | null
|        House1 | roomMap_kitchen     |         {...} | null
|        House2 | roomMap_livingRoom1 |         {...} | null
|        House1 | device_fridgeSensor |          null | {...}
|        House2 | device_fridgeSensor |          null | {...}
```

Now I would often read the same partition key. **Is this a bad design?**
And if yes how could i do better?

Comment: For those also scratching their head about key and index design, check out this post which has lots of examples: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-to-use-dynamodb-global-secondary-indexes-to-improve-query-performance-and-reduce-costs/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few reasons why you would want to have many distinct values for partition keys.

For example, every partition key is limited to one partition of storage (hence the name) with a maximum size of 10 GB. Which means that you will run into trouble if a certain key has, for example, a lot of sort keys causing it to require more than 10 GB of storage.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html

Also, if you only have a few partition keys and one of them is very popular and thus called a lot, you have a 'hot' partition. And since your read/write capacity is split evenly over all your partitions, you will either pay too much (if you set your R/W high enough, giving the hot partition enough R/W and the others too much), or you will get throttled.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-uniform-load.html

Note that AWS has, on several occassions like re:Invent 2018, said that they automatically *try* to compensate for hot partitions, without any additional cost to the customer. But don't count on that too much.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-design.html#bp-partition-key-throughput-bursting

In your case though, I don't really see a problem unless one house is going to have thousands of devices/rooms, or if the data for one or a few houses is extremly popular.

One thing to watch out for is the size of your json files (room map, dashboard config). If those files grow too big, the normal approach within AWS is to store them in S3 and add their location/id in DynamoDB. In that case, if you need those files, you get the id and go to S3 to look for it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Hieron! 
My use case is a bit more technical, I just tried to simplify it with that example. It may be possible to have lots of devices (not thousands, but ~ 1 thousand is possible). Also it could be possible that 95% data of house1 is requested.

Is it bad practice to use such partition keys: house1::roomMap_livingroom and house1::device_fridgeSensor?
Without a sort key?

Comment: No, that's a sensible solution and one that is at least occasionally recommended by AWS. So that's definitely one way forward.